# Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed. --detectOpenHandles

Tags: graphql, jestjs, apollo, apollo-server

I am going to test backend server running with Jest.
It success sometimes, but other times it shows error like this.
[image]

So if I use --detectOpenHandles flag as suggested, It always success without showing eny error.
This is test code.

```
  it("should be able to initialize a server (development)",async (done) => {
      // Before main() is called there is no active connection:

    expect(connection.readyState).toBe(0);
    return main({
      env: "dev",
      port: PORT,
    })
    .then(async (server: ApolloServer) => {
        // After main() got called, there is an active connection:
      expect(connection.readyState).toBe(1);
      await server.stop();
      done();
    })
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close(); //connection is mongoose.connection
  });
```

I am not sure why it fails when flag.
And it weird it sometimes success, and other times fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and managed to resolve it by returning a promise in the function passed to `afterAll`. For example:

```
afterAll(() => {
  return connection.close(); // connection.close() returns a promise
});
```

[Docs for reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#one-time-setup)

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the user's question, but causes the problem in the title nevertheless:

Switching from 
`testEnvironment: 'node',` to `testEnvironment: 'jsdom',` in `jest.config.js` seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully get it, but this worked for me like a charm:

Problem was in `Jest`'s `globalSetup`:

```
import server from "./../../graphql-basics/src/index.js";

export default async () => {
  global.httpServer = await server.listen();
};
```

Changed to:

```
import server from "./../../graphql-basics/src/index.js";

export default async () => {
  global.httpServer = await server;
};
```

Fixed the issue.

My remaining setup working 100% fine for a full example:

`teardown.js`

```
export default async () => {
  await global.httpServer.close();
};
```

`tests/sample.test.js`

```
test("test", () => {
  expect(1 + 2).toBe(3);
});
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.7.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./jest/setup.js",
    "globalTeardown": "./jest/teardown.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module"
}
```